# Angular + Jasmine: How to ignore/ mock one function in the tested component (not in a dependency)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, contentful

I know how to mock a function from a dependency, but now I have one function that is not in a dependency, it's in the actual component that I want to test. How can I tell jasmine to simply ignore it?

When I run `ng test` this test fails:

[image]

The reason for this is this function that I import from an external library:

```
import { documentToHtmlString } from '@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer';
```

(Contentful is a content managament service that I use in my project.)

In my component this function gets called here:

```
ngOnInit() {
  
  //the next line keeps the test from creating, I don't really care to test this function, how can I mock it?:
  this.serializeContentfulRichText(someContentfulTextDoesntMatter);
  
  // a lot more stuff that I actually need to test
  ...
}

serializeContentfulRichText(contentfulText: any) {
    return documentToHtmlString(contentfulText, this.myRenderingOptions);
}
```

When I delete the `documentToHtmlString` line and just return null the rest of the test works and I can test my whole component. But of course I can't just delete this line in my actual component, **I just want to ignore/mock it in my test.**

I tried it with a **spy**:

```
it('should create', () => {
    let spy = spyOn(component, 'serializeContentfulRichText')
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

But the spy doesn't get called and the component doesnt get created (Both expectations fail).

Comment: Is someContentfulTextDoesntMatter null/undefined when it fails? You can check for that, otherwise provide some content for someContentfulTextDoesntMatter eg: component.someContentfulTextDoesntMatter = 'mock content';

Comment: Hey thanks, but I tried and it still fails with the same error. I created a mock object for someContentfulTextDoesntMatter and also for this.myRenderingOptions and added them to the component as you said...

Comment: try putting `let spy = spyOn(component, 'serializeContentfulRichText')` line before first `fixture.detectChanges()`

Comment: that was it! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stub a method of a testing component, you need to do it after `TestBed.createComponent`, but before `fixture.detectChanges()`.

In this case, only constructor of the component has been executed, but not lifecycle hooks.

```js
it('should create', () => {
  // initialization
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeclarationScrolltextComponent);
  const component = fixture.componentInstance;
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();

  // installing spies
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'serializeContentfulRichText');
  
  // executing render
  fixture.detectChanges();

  // assertions
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```